# Message in / on iOS System Status Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, statusbar

How do I add a custom message in/on a status bar in an iOS app (see pictures)?

[image: http://jonathangurebo.tumblr.com/post/38709179103]

Here's another link to my picture: http://jonathangurebo.tumblr.com/post/38709197648
Here's the [App link](http://www.itunes.apple.com/se/app/skolmaten/id416550379?mt=8)

Comment: So do you want to add a message to Xcode itself? Or what?

Comment: ;) xcode is only an IDE.. you are talking about the ios system bar

Answer (score 6):

You can hide the default status bar and create a custom bar with the same height as the status bar and display it on the view. Apple does not allow you customize the status bar other than changing its color(gray/black), opacity(opaque/translucent) and visibility(hidden/visible).

Comment: but i think it is a kind of notification, have you lock on my pictures?

Comment: yes, I have looked them, Apple doesn't allow to edit status bar, Also the images you have uploaded have custom status bar with full screen app, as you can see that there is battery icon and time label is there.

Comment: This is how, for instance, the Twitter app does it.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to customize status bar.

There is another alternate.
Basically, we are not making any changes in status behavior. As it oppose to apple guidelines & rules.
So, keep the status bar as it is. And you can display the status message like the screenshot.

Please have a look at below demo class which will satisfy your requirement.

https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios

It is like a Android messages.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.